# How to put Kivy ScrollView on a Screen

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

Kivy Code:

```
GridLayout:

    Button:

    ScrollView:
```

Python Code:

```
class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='start'))
sm.add_widget(NormalScreen(name='game'))

class ChatBot(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

ChatBot().run()
```

I am trying to build my first `GUI`. But the problem is, that my ScrollView is not working. I need it to be on my normal Screen. Anyone knowing how to fix this problem?

Comment: I can not upload the full code, because Stack Overflow won't let me.

Comment: Share it on Google Drive

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DgI_vMwmzoTduNXM4c6WYXhI8VrH1WOZ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example illustrates a Scrollview of Stacklayout with Labels. Please refer to the example for details. The following Scrollview APIs were used in the example.

[ScrollView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html)

> layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
>
> **bar_color**
>  Color of horizontal / vertical scroll bar, in RGBA format.
>   bar_color is a ListProperty and defaults to [.7, .7, .7, .9].
>
> **bar_inactive_color**
>  Color of horizontal / vertical scroll bar (in RGBA format), when no scroll is happening.
>   bar_inactive_color is a ListProperty and defaults to [.7, .7, .7, .2].
>
> **bar_width**
>  Width of the horizontal / vertical scroll bar. The width is interpreted as a height for the horizontal bar.
>   bar_width is a NumericProperty and defaults to 2.
>
> **effect_cls**
>  Class effect to instantiate for X and Y axis.
>   effect_cls is an ObjectProperty and defaults to DampedScrollEffect.
>
> **scroll_type**
>  Sets the type of scrolling to use for the content of the scrollview. Available options are: [‘content’], [‘bars’],
>   [‘bars’, ‘content’].
>
> [‘content’]   Content is scrolled by dragging or swiping the content
>   directly.
>  [‘bars’]    Content is scrolled by dragging or swiping the
>   scoll bars.
>  [‘bars’, ‘content’]   Content is scrolled by either of
>   the above methods.
>  scroll_type is an OptionProperty and defaults
>   to [‘content’].

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    container = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SettingsScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.setup_scrollview, 1)

    def setup_scrollview(self, dt):
        self.container.bind(minimum_height=self.container.setter('height'))
        self.add_text_inputs()

    def add_text_inputs(self):
        for x in range(30):
            self.container.add_widget(Label(text="Label {}".format(x), size_hint_y=None, height=40))

    def new_message(self):
        msg = self.display.text
        print(msg)


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class ChatBot(App):

    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


ChatBot().run()
```

### chatbot.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<But@Button>:
    font_size: 20
    font_name: "Calibri"
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    size_hint: .7, .1
    background_normal: ''
    background_down: 'test.png'
    background_color: .88,.88,.88, 1

<Lab@Label>:
    font_size: 27
    font_name: "Calibri"
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1

<Grid@GridLayout>:

<ScreenManagement>:
    MenuScreen:
        name: 'start'
    SettingsScreen:
        name: 'game'

<MenuScreen>:

    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            BorderImage:
                border: 10, 10, 10, 10
                source: 'Blur-4K-Img08.jpeg'    # 'Blur-4K-Abstract-Wallpaper.png'
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        But:
            text: "START"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .3}
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'game'

        Lab:
            text: "Welcome to my ChatBot!"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .8}


<SettingsScreen>:
    display: entry
    message: send
    container: container

    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            BorderImage:
                border: 10, 10, 10, 10
                source: 'Blur-4K-Img08.jpeg'    # 'Blur-4K-Abstract-Wallpaper.png'
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

    GridLayout:
        rows: 3
        cols: 1
        spacing: 5
        padding: 5
        font_name: "Calibri"

        Button:
            text: "ChatBot"
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            size_hint: .7, .1
            background_normal: ''
            background_down: ''
            background_color: .88,.88,.88, 1
            font_size: 20

        ScrollView:
            size_hint: (1, .9)
            bar_width: 10
            bar_color: 1, 0, 0, 1   # red
            bar_inactive_color: 0, 0, 1, 1   # blue
            effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
            scroll_type: ['bars']

            StackLayout:
                id: container
                size_hint_y: None

        BoxLayout:
            spacing: 5
            size_hint: .7, .1

            TextInput:
                id: entry
                multiline: False
                font_size: 25

            Button:
                id: send
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                background_normal: 'send.jpg'
                background_down: 'test.png'
                background_color: .88,.88,.88, 1
                size_hint: .2, 1
                on_press: root.new_message()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Scrollview]

Comment: how to get the value of the checked checkbox?

Comment: Could you explain the reason behind `Clock.schedule_once`? I have a similar example but I have screen manager and when I try to go back to the screen with the scrollview I get an error and the app crashes and I think it relates to the clock.